# How to show a partial view of a Item in itemscontrol when scrolling?

Tags: wpf, scrollview, itemscontrol

The ItemContainer templates in my Listboxes and views can be somewhat big and showing alot of info. But when I scroll and the big item should start disappearing to the top or bottom it disappears completely instead of being partially visible. This gives jumpy and hectic scrolling which isn't really pretty or pleasent to use.

Is there any attribute or a easy solution to get the other behaviour.

Also can I set the scrollspeed inside the Scrollviewer somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [CanContentScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx) property of the ListBox's ScrollViewer to false.